# Convertir un object a datetime

Tags: python, pandas

como cambiar un dtype object en pandas a datatime, cuándo hago el pd.to_datetime me sale un error que no puedo convertir a datetime un datetime.time, Pero pandas esta reconociendo como object

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow!. Podrias compartir el código que tienes hasta el momento y asi poder ayudarte mejor? Un saludo :)

Comment: Sí, data_PNC = pd.read_csv(path_PNC)
data_CCS = pd.read_excel(path_CCS, sheet_name= "Query")

df_PNC = pd.DataFrame(data_PNC)
df_CCS = pd.DataFrame(data_CCS)

df_PNC.Date = pd.to_datetime(df_PNC.Date) df_PNC.CHECKDATE = pd.to_datetime(df_PNC.CHECKDATE)

Comment: Al querer convertir df_PNC.CHECKDATE = pd.to_datetime(df_PNC.CHECKDATE)      Me dice qué no se puede convertir un datetime.time a datetime. Pero me lo reconoce como object. y cuándo trato de convertirlo no deja.

Comment: Esta informacion que has compartido, ponla en tu pregunta :) . Puedes usar este link [edit]